# Remove option to choose between the three pages in Settings Page

Tags: uwp-xaml, template10

I am develop an UWP app, and I am using Template10 (Hamburguer Menu). In Settings Page, there is, by default, 3 pages: Settings, About and Privacy statement.

[image]

I want only one page - Settings

How do I remove that option to choose between the three pages? I already managed to remove it, but it always remains there.

Comment: If i am not wrong, Template 10 Settings Page is a Pivot. So you can remove the Pivot Item `Privacy Statement` and `About`. I don't have access to `Template10` as of now but can you check that?

Answer (score 2):

Please try to find the relative `Pivot` control in `Views->SettingsPage.xaml` of your project and delete or commented out the following two `PivotItems`, the "About and Privacy statement" will gone.

```
<!--  privacy  -->
<PivotItem
    Padding="0"
    DataContext="{Binding SettingsPartViewModel}"
    Header="Privacy statement">
    <ScrollViewer Margin="0,0,-12,0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        ...
    </ScrollViewer>
</PivotItem>
<!--  about  -->
<PivotItem Header="About">
    <RelativePanel DataContext="{Binding AboutPartViewModel}">
        ...
    </RelativePanel>
</PivotItem>
```